# how can I read a file in my local machine using php or jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a '.txt' file in my machine I want to read the content of the file using jquery or php

without uploading it server. Is there any way please tell me.

thank you....

Comment: Aside from doing something odd like mounting a network share from your box on the target server via VPN tunnel or something like this...no. How do you expect the server to access your computer? Only other solution might be to have a local webserver running and access that from your server, but I don't see any point in doing that. It's only an additional point of failure.

Comment: read from where? server or from your localhost?

Comment: in my local system some where in c:/ or D:/

Comment: who given minus point ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's not  - otherwise you could read personal files from user's computers